# Empathy account manager "crashes"

Tags: 12.04, empathy

I use empathy only for my gtalk account. But recently I cannot open the account manager window (F4). It does open, loading a little while but when loaded the information it shuts.

I have read quite a few forums and the bug reports and seems like it is due to some extra parameter google included in the profile that the account manager cannot parse (or something like that anyway.. )

I have run empathy from console and this is the error I get when account manager closes:

```
ERROR:empathy-contact-widget.c:402:contact_widget_details_update_edit: assertion failed: (spec != NULL)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried the suggestion from other question here to delete keys from gnome2/keyrings and delete Empathy config, it didn't help.

Also are there any plugins for empathy? I find the basic functionality very limited. I used Pidgin before but it had some downsides as well. I cannot believe there isn't any nice looking, well developed IM client for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can set yourself offline after launching the chat window and when you press F4 this time the windows hangs for some time before Google Talk is activated again. I have learned it from:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145792